# How to change PostgreSQL Studio's inactivity timeout?

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, jakarta-ee, postgresqlstudio

I want to increase [PostgreSQL's Studio](http://www.postgresqlstudio.org/) login/session time out time. When I leave PostgreSQL Studio to idle just for some time, I get the following message:

> You have been logged out due to inactivity. Please relogin or exit.

[image]

I am using PostgreSQL from BigSQL 5.0.3 package bundle. Actually, I am researching about compability of MS SQL Server and PostgreSQL queries.

As I am using Postgres now for learning purpose rather than security, I feel it annoying to login frequently.

How can I increase the login/session timeout inside PostgreSQL Studio?

Comment: [Are you sure that's the actual error message](https://www.google.com/#q="Please+relogin+or+exit+postgres")

Comment: @ta.speot.is, Yes that's the actual error message..

Comment: "postgres" has no "web console". Whatever you're using, it's not just PostgreSQL, it's some other part of the bundle you're using. Is this PgPHPAdmin you're talking about? Something else? (I've never heard of BigSQL)

Comment: It's PostgreSQL studio..BigSQL is the package bundle that comes with Postgres, Hadoop, Zookeeper, Hive etc.

Comment: @user3306594 Well, what's the "etc". What are you actually using? There should be an about page or help page somewhere that tells you what the web console component is.

Comment: Re-tagged with `postgresqlstudio` as this is clearly not a Postgres question

Comment: @user3306594 is talking about PostgreSQL Studio http://www.postgresqlstudio.org/ . See corrected message and picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres itself doesn't have an idle connection timeout. This is coming from something else.

Comment: @user3306594 Sounds like you might want to use something better supported and documented instead, then.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the timeout value is hard-coded to 30 minutes in PostgreSQL Studio. You should only see that if you are not using Studio at all for 30 minutes. Its a pretty simple matter to move that property to the config file so it can be changed. We just need to write a patch.

The timeout is to prevent Studio from holding open idle connections to PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL Studio uses connection pooling to manage connections back to the database so if the browser connection goes away without logging out, we need a way to remove those connections.

Comment: I've tried changing the session-timeout inside conf/web.xml to a bigger value however this does not fix the problem, the same message is shown after a period of time. I think the timeout is **less** than 30 minutes.